# Transverse intersection of two fixed point submanifolds?

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, transversality

Let a finite group $G$ act smoothly on a smooth manifold $M$ and $H_1, H_2$ be subgroups of $G$ such that the set  $H_1\cup H_2$ generates $G$. Moreover, assume that
$$
\dim(M^{H_1})+\dim(M^{H_2})-\dim(M^G)=\dim(M)
$$ 
(notice that $M^G=M^{H_1}\cap M^{H_2}$ since $H_1\cup H_2$ generates  $G$). Is it true that $M^{H_1}$ and $M^{H_2}$ are transverse?